# proving that plane tangent a surface on axis $z$ is the same

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Show that all planes tangent to the surface $z=f\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)$ on the same level surface cut to the $z$-axis at the same point.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Can you precise the question with what you’ve try and where you encounter difficulties. Also, I imagine that you mean *level curve* instead of *level surface*

Answer (score 0):

*Hint.* Given a function $z=f(x,y),$ since $$\mathrm dz=f_x\mathrm dx+f_y\mathrm dy,$$ it follows that for small values of $\Delta x,\,\Delta y,$ an approximate value for $\mathrm dz$ is $$\Delta z=f_x\Delta x+f_y\Delta y,$$ or $$z-z_0=f_x(x-x_0)+f_y(y-y_0),$$ where $z_0$ is the value of $f$ at the point $(x_0,y_0).$

The last equation is the tangent plane to the surface $z=f(x,y)$ at the point $(x_0,y_0).$ Find this equation for your function and for some fixed value of $z.$ Since the $z$ axis is given by the equations $x=0,\,y=0,$ put this in your tangent plane and show that you have constant $z$ even when you vary the point $(x_0,y_0,z_0),$ where $z_0$ is fixed.

To find the partial derivatives of your function, make a substitution  and use the chain rule.

Comment: I don't khow how finding the partial derivates

Comment: @SantiagoCelisPatiño Let $u=\sqrt{x^2+y^2},$ then use the chain rule, so that $f_x,$ for example, is given by $$f_uu_x=f_u\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}2x\right).$$

Comment: thank you so much